# How to pass a single string in AJAX [without key]

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to pass a single quoted string in data without key.

I write a code below :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'MY_API_URL',
        data: "HATETH",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            console.log(r);
        }
});
```

it not works..

**Please help me to do this. Is it possible or not?**

Comment: it will work but on the server you will need to handle this by fetching raw POST data.

Comment: OKay let me try@jcubic

Comment: Why bother with `contentType` if you aren't sending JSON?

Comment: I just checking .. it works with it or not.. @ChrisG

now i got solution with stringify..

Comment: Just use `$.post('MY_API_URL', "HATETH", function (r) {...});`. It all comes down to the server-side handling anyway.